# Protractor: How to Drag and Drop without using an element?

Tags: protractor

Normally, drag and drop are done using 2 elements.

But, what if I have a dynamic grid, and I want to select a part of it by click-hold and dragging it then release. (similar to drag and drop)

I was able to get the x and y coordinates already, but I am not sure how to make it work without an element.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an element is required.
After using the element (body), I was able to make drag and drop work.

Answer (score 0):

```
var offsetx = dndoffset.x;
var offsety = dndoffset.y;
browser.waitForAngular();
this.getTargetIndex(<ObjectToBeDragged>,function (targetIndex) {
  var targetElement = element.all(by.repeater(<ng-repeat value>)).get(targetIndex);
  targetElement.getLocation().then(function (location) {
    offsetx = Math.round(offsetx + location.x);
    browser.actions().mouseMove(<ObjectToBeDragged>)
      .mouseDown()
      .mouseMove(targetElement)
      .mouseMove(targetElement, {x: offsetx, y: offsety})
      .mouseUp().perform();
  });
  browser.waitForAngular();
});
```

The above is the snippet I am using to drag and drop. You always have element in the DOM (even it is dynamic). You have to pick the right one and place it there.

Since we have the ng-repeat, we are using by.repeater() to locate the element dynamically.